# Cannot call getJSON method to fetch data

Tags: php, jquery, getjson

I am trying to fetch some JSON data. I can access the data just fine in a regular web browser, like this: http://www.ebrent.net/apis/tsp.php?fund=G+Fund&start=2003-01-01&end=2004-01-01, but I cannot get it to work in jQuery. What am I doing wrong?

Please take a look at my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MrSnrub/mq31hwuj/

```
var tsp_api = '//www.ebrent.net/apis/tsp.php?start=2003-01-01&end=2004-01-01';

$.getJSON( tsp_api, function(json) {

  // This alert never gets called.
  alert("Success!");

  // Set the variables from the results array
  var data = json;
  // console.log('Data : ', data);

  // Set the div's text
  $('#div-data').text(data);

});
```

Comment: Is www.ebrent.net  CORS enabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the result because the remote site doesn't have [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) enabled:
If you look at the console, you'll see:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://www.ebrent.net/apis/tsp.php?start=2003-01-01&end=2004-01-01.
>   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

---

You can bypass CORS by using something like [anyorigin.com](http://anyorigin.com/), i.e.:

```
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get/?url=http%3A//www.ebrent.net/apis/tsp.php%3Fstart%3D2003-01-01%26end%3D2004-01-01&callback=?', function(data){
    $('#div-data').html(data.contents);
});
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the error in console? I open Firebug and go to Console, but all I see is a red X; I don't see anything mentioning Cross Origin Request Blocked.

Comment: Your example on jsfiddle shows 2 errors, the 1st is mixing content( request http using https),  2nd the one I've posted above.

Comment: I thought using `//www.ebrent.net` instead of `http://www.ebrent.net` or `https://www.ebrent.net` was supposed to take care of the mixing content error.

Answer (score 0):

This works if you run the your server without using https. Note fetchApi was used instead of jquery Library as its not readily available in the browser

```
var tsp_api = 'https://www.ebrent.net/apis/tsp.php?start=2003-01-01&end=2004-01-01';


function fetchData(url) {
      return fetch(url, {
          method: 'get'
      }).then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
      }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log(error);
      });
  }
 fetchData(tsp_api).then((data)=> console.log(data)).catch((err)=> console.log(err));
```

This won't work on jsfiddle using HTTPS, the browser will refuse to load any resources over HTTP. As you've tried, changing the API URL to have HTTPS instead of HTTP typically resolves this issue. However, your ebrent.net did not allow CoRS for HTTPS connections. Because of this, you won't be able to get your result for jsfiddle